# How much power does it cost if I register the sensors and keep it running in the background?

Tags: android, sensors

I want to write an app that has a background service to keep getting the sensor values all the time, but dont know if that will consume too much power, does anyone has some knowledge of this? any reply will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you be more specific about which sensors you are talking about ? Their power consumption varies greatly. For example the GPS sensor is an absolute battery killer

Comment: @Teovald, sorry I'm talking about sensors of type like `Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE` or others in this constant list: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html, I didnt see a type like Sensor.TYPE_GPS, so i thought it was not a sensor...

Comment: The sensors typicaly don't use much power you can use the getPower() method to find out how much.  The real problem is that for continuas monitoring you have to have the cpu active and running code regularly as well, the power used here is probobly more than the sensors themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This varies from sensor to sensor, and device to device.

On average, your most power hungry sensors are the GPS, accelerometer and gyroscope. Leaving these on in the background will start showing battery drain within an hour usually.

After that, the light sensor and compass are much less battery intensive, but if you use them for long enough even they'll affect battery life.

Answer (score 0):

Consumption depends on many factors, so it's difficult to evaluate the impact of this task.
Maybe you can test, 2 hours with and 2 hours without to see the difference

Answer (score -2):

Your fundamental application design is flawed if you require sensor data while your activities are in the background. You should only need to collect this kind of information between onResume and onPause.